# CodeIgniter Multiple database use without changing existing code for first database

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have successfully configured a second database with codeigniter and was able to create a table. The problem is now that every previously existing lines of code that was using `$this->db` now uses the second database so naturally it pops an error. Let me explain with a bit more details:

I use the migration library of codeigniter and in a new migration, I create the database with dbforge like so `$this->dbforge->create_database('website_store')`. So far so good, then I connect to this database using `$DB2 = $this->load->database('store', TRUE);` and create a table. All is good here as well.

Then the migration ends and codeigniter tries to update the migration table to push the latest version, but looks into the `store` database instead of the default database, so it pops this error:

```
Table 'website_store.migrations' doesn't exist
UPDATE `migrations` SET `version` = 45
```

Hopefully someone knows about using multiple database and the migration library. By the way, in the database.php file, it is set to use the default database: `$active_group = "default";`, not the store database so it should work. It looks like the migration library sees that there is already a database loaded, feels lazy and uses that one instead.

**NOTE:**
Looks like these guys had similar problems that they fixed by setting 'pconnect' to 'false', but it would be nice to keep a connection to both database:

[Convenient Way to Load Multiple Databases in Code Igniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917957/convenient-way-to-load-multiple-databases-in-code-igniter)

[Error Using Multiple Database In CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125961/error-using-multiple-database-in-codeigniter)

Comment: Ok, I went with the "pconnect" to "false" solution. Not what I wanted to do but it works.

Answer (score 1):

In CI i have dealt with multiple databases using:

```
function readFromOtherDB(){
    $config = array(
        'hostname' => "XXX",
        'username' => "XXX",
        'password' => "XXX",
        'database' => "XXX",
        'dbdriver' => "mysql",
        'dbprefix' => "",
        'pconnect' => FALSE,
        'db_debug' => TRUE,
        'cache_on' => FALSE,
        'cachedir' => "",
        'char_set' => "utf8",
        'dbcollat' => "utf8_general_ci"
    );

    $otherDb = $this->ci->load->database($config, true);

    $query = $otherDb->get_where('users', array('email' => $_email));

    $otherDb->close();
}
```

Comment: I don't think the close() is needed when pconnect is set to false. Nonetheless, I was looking for a way to do it without setting pconnect=false